# Ascii codec cannot decode HTML when saving to file in python

Tags: python, encoding

I have a text that is part of html. I would like to save it to a file.

This works fine in debug mode in Eclipse, but fails on runtime from shell. I am using a short example of html that fails.

```
xx = '<input type="hidden" name="charset_test" value="€,´,€,´,水,Д,Є" />'
with codecs.open('myfile.htm'), 'wb', encoding="utf-8") as output:
    output.write(data)
```

and I get:

```
 Exception 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position XXX: ordinal not in range(128)
```

where XXX is the position in the relevant file of the "strange" symbols, such as the EURO sign.

Why is this working from Eclipse and not from shell? How do I solve this?

I tried

```
HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape()
unquote()
unicode()
```

Nothing worked...

Comment: Is `xx` an actual variable in the code or just a fragment of the file you're giving as the example?

Comment: it's just a fragment, I zoomed in on it using the XXX location, since the original is a very big file

Comment: Haven't you solved yet the problem? The file you're trying to process, what's its encoding?

Comment: it's not a file, it's a result of a url call to a remote file.

Comment: Well, there you have to know what's the encoding of the remote file, and the encoding of the http connection. Maybe they are different and this may yield problems

Comment: How would I check the encoding of the connection?

Comment: It is in the connection header. If you have Firefox and Firebug for example, you can see it within the Net tab. There you have the get requests sent and the header where is defined the `charset` is `Content-Type` which for this page is `Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8`

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me...

```
# coding=utf-8

import codecs

data = '<input type="hidden" name="charset_test" value="€,´,€,´,水,Д,Є" />'
with codecs.open('myfile.htm', 'wb', encoding="utf-8") as output:
    output.write(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

...but if the source data is already UTF-8 encoded, and you also want to write UTF-8 data, there's no need to decode it to a Python `unicode` object, then re-encode back to UTF-8. You can just do...

```
# coding=utf-8

data = '<input type="hidden" name="charset_test" value="€,´,€,´,水,Д,Є" />'
with open('myfile.htm', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(data)
```